# Login still appears even after user is logged in (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, magento2

I would like help creating this code, I want "enter" to exit after the user has logged in. Next, before the user logs in, the "Login" option appears. What happens is that when the user logs in the "Enter" span keeps appearing and I wanted to hide it when the user logs in but I don't know how to start.

`

```
const AccountMenu = React.lazy(() => import('@magento/venia-ui/lib/components/AccountMenu'));

/**
 * The AccountTrigger component is the call to action in the site header
 * that toggles the AccountMenu dropdown.
 *
 * @param {Object} props
 * @param {Object} props.classes - CSS classes to override element styles.
 */
const AccountTrigger = props => {
    const talonProps = useAccountTrigger();
    const {
        accountMenuIsOpen,
        accountMenuRef,
        accountMenuTriggerRef,
        setAccountMenuIsOpen,
        handleTriggerClick
    } = talonProps;

    const classes = useStyle(defaultClasses, props.classes);
    const rootClassName = accountMenuIsOpen ? classes.root_open : classes.root;
    const { formatMessage } = useIntl();
    const [{ isSignedIn }] = useUserContext();

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <AccountTriggerContainer>
                <div className={rootClassName} ref={accountMenuTriggerRef}>
                    <button
                        aria-label={formatMessage({
                            id: 'accountTrigger.ariaLabel',
                            defaultMessage: 'Toggle My Account Menu'
                        })}
                        className={`${classes.trigger} trigger-action`}
                        onClick={handleTriggerClick}
                        data-cy="AccountTrigger-trigger"
                    >
                        <AccountChip
                            fallbackText={formatMessage({
                                id: 'accountTrigger.buttonFallback',
                                defaultMessage: 'Bem vindo(a)'
                            })}
                            shouldIndicateLoading={true}
                        />
                        <span className='signin'>
                            Entrar
                        </span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <Suspense fallback={null}>
                    <AccountMenu
                        ref={accountMenuRef}
                        accountMenuIsOpen={accountMenuIsOpen}
                        setAccountMenuIsOpen={setAccountMenuIsOpen}
                    />
                </Suspense>
            </AccountTriggerContainer>
        </Fragment>
    );
};

export default AccountTrigger;

AccountTrigger.propTypes = {
    classes: shape({
        root: string,
        root_open: string,
        trigger: string
    })
};
```

`